# Convert Datetime datatype to date only and the month is in word SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

How can I convert `datetime` to date and the month into words?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), customer_type.valid_until, 0) AS 'Valid Until' 
FROM billing
```

I do get the date. But I would like to do is to convert the month in word.

Thanks!

Comment: check out `style` in `convert()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 or  `format()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Squirrel Thank you so much for the help! Got my answer